# Why including <string.h> in .cpp file causes compilation errors (while including it .h file is ok)

Tags: c++

I have a strange compilation error when using:

```
#include <string.h>
```

in .cpp file:

```
/usr/include/string.h:47:8: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
        size_t __n) __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
        ^
/usr/include/string.h:50:56: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
 extern void *memmove (void *__dest, const void *__src, size_t __n)
                                                        ^
/usr/include/string.h:59:18: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
         int __c, size_t __n)
                  ^
/usr/include/string.h:66:42: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
 extern void *memset (void *__s, int __c, size_t __n) __THROW __nonnull ((1));    /usr/include/string.h:47:8: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
        size_t __n) __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));
        ^
/usr/include/string.h:50:56: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
 extern void *memmove (void *__dest, const void *__src, size_t __n)
                                                        ^
/usr/include/string.h:59:18: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
         int __c, size_t __n)
                  ^
/usr/include/string.h:66:42: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
 extern void *memset (void *__s, int __c, size_t __n) __THROW __nonnull ((1));
                                          ^
/usr/include/string.h:69:56: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
 extern int memcmp (const void *__s1, const void *__s2, size_t __n)
                                          ^
/usr/include/string.h:69:56: error: ‘size_t’ has not been declared
 extern int memcmp (const void *__s1, const void *__s2, size_t __n)
```

while putting the same line code in .h file, does not give any errors.

I'm confused, what is the problem ?

Comment: You need to update your question to show a minimal test case.

Comment: It'll be due to the ordering of dependent headers but we can only guess because you're not showing any of your source.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for there to be a difference here between including the header from a `.h` and from a `.cpp`. Literally impossible. Next time, post a [testcase](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (I cannot emphasise how important this is).

However, you are probably including *some other header* in your `.cpp`, which defines `size_t`, masking the bug. Yes, this is a bug. Standard headers should work in isolation and, apparently, on your implementation, this one doesn't.

However, since you should be including C++ `<cstring>`, not C `<string.h>`, it's moot.

If you do that and still have a problem, then you messed something up. And we cannot tell what that is without a testcase.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why you'd be getting that error, but in general the use of `<string.h>` is deprecated for C++, so although it often works, you can't expect it to. `<string>` is the C++ header that contains the string class defined in the `std` namespace.

`<string.h>` contains the C string functions and definitions. In C++, if you want those older functions you should use `<cstring>`. I think if you mix things around in C++ you'll get namespace issues and such, which may be causing your error.

Comment: Hm, size_t should definitely be defined in cstring: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t - what compiler are you using? Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407193/clang-not-identifying-ptrdiff-t-size-t-wchar-t-while-parsing-ast